# how to import cardano-cli project into dependecies under cabal?

Tags: cardano-node, cabal, nix-shell

I've got the following nix-shell:

```
let
   src = builtins.fetchGit {
      url = "git@github.com:input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git";
      # url = "https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git";
      ref = "main";
      # rev = "4ecc1d9350e9897557d2a15699a9ace7df665a01";
    };
    in
let
  packages = import "${src}/default.nix" {};
in
with packages;
with pkgs;

mkShell {
  src = builtins.toString ./.;

  buildInputs = [
    wget gnupg coreutils
    which less curl ripgrep tree
    gitMinimal openssh man-db
  ] ++ (with plutus-apps; [
    haskell-language-server
    cabal-install
    hlint
    (haskell.project.ghcWithPackages (ps: with ps; [
      playground-common
      plutus-contract
      plutus-ledger
      plutus-ledger-api
      plutus-pab
      plutus-tx
      plutus-tx-plugin
      plutus-doc
      plutus-use-cases
      # cardano-node.cardano-cli
      freer-extras]))]);
  GIT_SSL_CAINFO = "${cacert}/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt";
  LANG = "C.UTF-8";
  LC_ALL = "C.UTF-8";
  PAGER="less -R";
  shellHook = ''
    ulimit -Sv 8388608
    ulimit -v 10485760
  ''; }
```

Under cabal project it always fails with error if I just add cardano-cli in build-depends

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the following lines:

```
let packages = import "${src}/default.nix" {};
cardano_pkgs = import "${cardano-node}/shell.nix" {};
in
  with packages;
  with pkgs; with cardano_pkgs;
```

and add cardano-cli to packages search

```
 ...
 plutus-doc
 plutus-use-cases
 cardano-cli
 freer-extras]))]);
 ...
```